# Search for value in json file to get number (python)

Tags: python, json, search

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "response": {
        "holidays": [
            {
                "name": "New Year's Day",
                "description": "New Year\u2019s Day is celebrated many countries such as in India on the January 1 in the Gregorian calendar.",
                "country": {
                    "id": "in",
                    "name": "India"
                },
                "date": {
                    "iso": "2021-01-01",
                    "datetime": {
                        "year": 2021,
                        "month": 1,
                        "day": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": [
                    "Optional holiday"
                ],
                "locations": "All",
                "states": "All"
            },
            {
                "name": "Lohri",
                "description": "Lohri is a restricted holiday in India",
                "country": {
                    "id": "in",
                    "name": "India"
                },
                "date": {
                    "iso": "2021-01-13",
                    "datetime": {
                        "year": 2021,
                        "month": 1,
                        "day": 13
                    }
                },
                "type": [
                    "National holiday"
                ],
                "locations": "All",
                "states": "All"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my json file saved as dates.json.
I want to search for New Year's day value in the key name and then get the value of the iso key.
How can i do that?
I am a beginner in python and json. so please tell me how to do this
Is there any search algorith or a library that can help me?

Comment: Check out the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module which would import this JSON as a dictionary Pyhthon object that you can iterate over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is using the modules json and jsonpath-rw-ext.

Use json module to read the json file and jsonpath-rw-ext to parse/filter.

https://github.com/sileht/python-jsonpath-rw-ext

I made it work for your example. Take a look at this.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import jsonpath_rw_ext

with open('dates.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    result = jsonpath_rw_ext.parse("$..holidays[?(@.name=='New Year\\'s Day')]").find(data)
    print([x.value for x in result])
```

To get the iso value use the code below.

[image]

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import jsonpath_rw_ext

with open('dates.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    result = jsonpath_rw_ext.parse("$..holidays[?(@.name=='New Year\\'s Day')].date.iso").find(data)
    print(result[0].value)
```